# running a java graphics program with command prompt

Tags: java, graphics, command-prompt, putty

At my university, if we want to program on our personal computers we connect to the main computer lab using a program called "PuTTY". This would be fine, however, programming a graphics program requires permission to open a new window so our website states just to use Command Prompt to run the program and it should work. When I run it, I get the same error message as I do on PuTTY how do I fix this?
Here is the error code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DrawingPanel$1
    at DrawingPanel.<init>(DrawingPanel.java:300)
    at Mini2Driver.main(Mini2Driver.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DrawingPanel$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

Thanks please let me know if you need anymore information

Comment: Check to see you have all the classes file required to run the program. You may need to recompile the program to be sure

Comment: `At my university, if we want to program on our personal computers we connect to the main computer lab using a program called "PuTTY".` And yet we're still cutting education budgets...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I recompiled DrawingPanel.java and no errors showed up and retested on Command Prompt still same error

Comment: Can we see the code / the command line you're running?

Comment: How are you running, what is the command line?

Comment: I compile with PuTTY and run on CMD. I'm currently trying to fix my CMD because it says javac is unrecognized

Comment: Ok so I compiled with CMD with no errors but still cannot open a drawing panel window for the graphic

Comment: Where's your code? Specifically, where do you declare DrawingPanel and then try to instantiate it? The people who supply answers on Stack Overflow have, collectively, millenia of programming experience. To my knowledge, however, not a single one of us has psychic abilities that allow us to see your code without you first posting it.

Comment: The code doesn't really matter in this case because its basic code meant to test the graphics pop up window. My issue is that it works fine at my university's computer lab aka where my PuTTY connects to, but on my personal computer it doesn't work (FYI I'm using the same code in both cases) and according to my professors, CMD should allow me to run graphics programs on my personal computer. Therefore, I would just like to know how to get my CMD to do just that.

Comment: But if you really need to see it, here is a snip-it                 `DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(size, size);
                Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                LearnGraphics.drawRectangle(g, size, "top", "left");
                delay(300);`